# Where Akita Store Store data by default without using persistState plugin

Tags: angular, angular-akita, akita

I am trying to explore Akita in Angular application. I implemented it for one of my Entity but I am unable to find where Akita saving data in the browser.

I saw one of a plugin to [persist-state](https://netbasal.gitbook.io/akita/enhancers/persist-state) but if we will not use that where we can find our stored data without redux dev-tool?

Answer (score 0):

Akita is not persisting any state by default: It's all living just in memory as long as the store object exists. You can get the whole state with [`getValue()`](https://datorama.github.io/akita/docs/query#getvalue) or using [`select()`](https://datorama.github.io/akita/docs/query#select) as an Observable.

Answer (score 0):

1. For non persistent stores (regular stores), you have to use the [redux tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd)
2. For persistent stores, by default, Akita will store the data in the localstore. You will therefore find your data back in that [localstore](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/storage/localstorage/)

Answer (score -1):

Hello **Rishabh Garg**,

Thanks for the question, I had the same question. This what I found in the internet. Even I'm using Akita having the same question in mind, but I haven't followed **persistState** as this stores data in browser storage. According to our requirement we can not expose data, so we went with services, on refresh we called observable again. This worked well for us.

In Angular applications, data can be stored in several ways without using the persistState property. The persistState property is typically used in the context of state management libraries like ngrx/store to enable storing the application state in local storage or session storage for persistence between page reloads.

If you want to store data without using persistState, you can consider the following options:

Component State: You can store data in the component itself by using component properties or class variables. However, this data will be lost when the component is destroyed (e.g., navigating to another route or component).

Service: Create a shared service to hold and manage data that should be accessible across multiple components. By providing the service at the application level or a specific module level, the data stored in the service will persist as long as the service instance is active.

Local Variables: Store data in local variables or arrays within your application's code. These variables will be available as long as the application is running, but they will not persist between page reloads or when navigating to different routes.

Browser APIs: You can use browser APIs like localStorage or sessionStorage to store data in the client's browser. This allows data to persist even when the user navigates away from the application or reloads the page. However, be cautious with sensitive data, as these storage mechanisms are accessible by other scripts on the same domain.

Keep in mind that using browser storage APIs (such as localStorage or sessionStorage) comes with their own limitations and considerations, such as storage size limits and security concerns. Additionally, it's essential to be mindful of data privacy and security, especially when handling sensitive information.

In summary, the way you choose to store data in an Angular application without using persistState depends on the scope and requirements of your data and how long you need it to be available during the application's lifecycle.